# SocketException (Timeout) only when running as scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, .net, windows, socket

I'm running a C# web-scrapper application (that I wrote) on a Windows Server 2003 instance under a user belonging to the local Administrator group. When I run it within a desktop/remote-desktop session the application runs successfully but when I schedule it to run under the same user/security-context outside of the desktop session, all socket connections timeout. The scheduled task calls a batch file which in-turn calls the application.

The Windows Server 2003 instance has a very basic configuration and isn't even connected to a domain.

I cannot find anything in any firewall or security configuration which is preventing this but maybe I have overlooked something, can anyone be of any assistance?

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not > properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond X.X.X.X:443
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult > asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Windows Firewall/ICS is disabled.